# can not stop animating UIActivity Indicator View in another class

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am using a UIActivity Indicator View named as process.

I declare property in main.h class,and synthesize in main .m

i am using this to indicate user connecting web on a button click.

And `[process startAnimating]` that indicator in button click.

But I write code to connect web services in another class named webservices,now i need to stop animating that process in this web services.

For that i am writing code in webservices.m

```
main *obj = [[main alloc]init];
[obj.process stopAnimating];
```

But it not works.

can any one pls help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `process` property is declared in your first class (`main`?).
You need to reference it from the same object as the first time: `[mainObj.process stopAnimating]`. You need to have a reference to the original instance of `main`.

You can make `main` a singleton or, much better, you can define a delegate protocol for `webservices` and `main` can tap as a delegate. This way `webservices` can notify `main` when it's done processing and `main` can stop the animation.

Answer (score 0):

```
main *obj = [[main alloc]init];
[obj.process stopAnimating];
```

you are creating another object of your main class here and stoping its process' activity indicator... rather than creating a new object you need to refer that process with which you have called `[process startAnimating]`

suppose i have one class

```
class ABC
{

//  Construction/Destruction
public:
                     ABC();
    virtual         ~ABC();
// member 
    int var1;

};
```

Now i am creating object of class ABC in file XYZ.cpp

```
ABC *abc_object1 = new ABC;
abc_object1->var1 = 5;
```

Now i want to use this abc_object1's var1 in another class PQR.cpp

if i create another object as

```
ABC *abc_object2 = new ABC;
printf("value is %d",abc_object2->var1);
```

the value would be null or garbage and not 5 as we have set in XYZ.cpp because it is two different object/instance of the same class. you need to pass that abc_object1 from XYZ.cpp to PQR.cpp somehow... by function's argument most likely...

same applies to your code also... i hope this simple example clears your fundamentals of class

Comment: i am using object-c language,any how what ever language i did n't get what u r saying simply you are saying "you need to pass that abc_object1 from XYZ.cpp to PQR.cpp" how can i pass it in my code

Comment: like you pass normal variable in function... if you use [navController pushViewController:viewController1]; you need to take one uiactivityindicator variable in viewController1 and before pushing you need to assign the  uiactivityindicator to your process from where you're pushing it...